# MVC return type File() only return file not file name itself

Tags: typescript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want get from my endpoint the file. Just in case it exists on my PC.

So googling answer I got this result to get File from Backend to front end. Here is endpoint

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileContentResult GetCSVFile()
    {
        string filename = "test.csv"; // Make this dynamic from the actual file
        byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Gubber\\Desktop\\" + filename);

        return File(filedata, "text/csv", "test.csv"); // byte data // content-type // fileDownload Name
    }
```

on front-end on button click you should get this file. Here I call endpoint

```js
 async exportCSVData(): Promise<void> {
            console.log('exportCSVData');
            const file = await companyService.getCSVFile();
            console.log(file);// just prints in console "guts" of file just it

            this.fileAutoDownload(file, 'test.csv'); //bad I wont name given from back-end
        },
```

So  my question is how to get FileName what is gor from back-end using return type `File()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The filename should be present in the header. You'll need to change what `getCSVFile` returns.

Comment: Can you give me example? I am new to MVC stuff so I do not get how to apply something to header.